# Offline Web App using Angular JS , Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm a beginner to hybrid mobile porpgramming.

Our requirement is to build a Offline Web App that can work on Laptop/Desktop and eventually use PhoneGap framework to make the App run on tablets/smartphones.

We have decided to use AngularJS ,Twitter Bootstrap for UI Frameworks and Rest API using .Net as the web server.

Our biggest concern is the size of data to be stored in offline mode for the web App.  HTML5 Web Storage has a limitation of 5 MB and HTML5 Web SQL Database is deprecated. We are going to use PhoneGap SQLLite database for offline storage in tablets/smartphones.

My questions are below:

1) How do I evaluate the size of database rows (data) that needs to be stored in HTML5 Web Storage ?

2) Assuming the data size exceeds 5MB, what would be the alternative option to store data in offline mode for a web App?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into IndexDB this allows you to request how much space you need.  There is a shim that works over WebSQL as well just in case you run on safari.

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Can I use information http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

Under phone gap I am not sure storage limitations are the same but I don't use this so can not confirm.  But I suspect it would be what ever limit a device places on an app.

If PhoneGap's WebSQL interface is mapped to the SQLLite engine and not relying on the OS browsers implementation then using IndexDB will work as well with the shim so no special code for the device.  (I highly recommend testing this early though!)

Comment: I will look into indexedDB. However I would like to evaluate if the size of data from database falls well less than 5 MB. What approach can be used to find if the data from database when stored in HTML5 Web Storage consumes less than 5 MB Storage. Do I program a POC , save a database row in HTML5 Web Storage and find the size of data, multiply with the maximum number of rows of data?

Comment: don't forget you can use compression as well if needed.

Comment: Before I decide on the option for Offline Web Storage , I would like to evaluate the size of data from our database. Can you suggest me an approach to do that? once I evaluate the size of data, I can use the compression techniques if needed. My preferred choice would be to use Web Storage.

Comment: The easiest to implement is using JSON and checking the string length.  This isn't necessarily the optimal solution though it depends on your date.

Comment: I beleive I need a write a program to fetch the data from database , store it in local storage and then evaluate the size of storage using storage using alert(1024 * 1024 * 5 - unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(localStorage))).length);

Answer (score 0):

I beleive I need a write a program to fetch the data from database , store it in local storage and then evaluate the size of storage using storage using

```
 alert(1024 * 1024 * 5 - unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(localStorage))).length);
```